# Update dependent data in DB - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

[image]
in it, data such as volume are dependent on the "margin" column, as the height calculated in the volume is height - margin, so when I edit some data used in calculations such as margin, the data is updated but the calculations are not redone:

[image]

Código de atualização no controller

```
public function update(Requeste $request){
   $pool = Pool::find($request -> id) -> update($request->all());
   return redirect("view");
}
```

I expected that when updating the data used in calculations, the calculations would also be redone and updated

Comment: You would either have to update this method to perform the calculations here, or create a database trigger to do it server-side. In general however, you should avoid storing simple calculated values like this in the database and instead store just the basic dimensions, then perform the calculations on the client side as you need them.

Comment: do you save calculations on database? be careful with portuguese on english SO.

Comment: Is `Requeste` in `update(Requeste $request)` a typo?

Answer (score 0):

On your Model, create following function:

```
public function handleUpdate(){
   $this->update([
                'volume' => $this->lenght * $this->width * $this->height,
                // AND SO ON
                ]);
}
```

And call this function after updating the Model. You can also use Laravel Callbacks, and Observers.

```
public function update(Request $request){
   $pool = Pool::find($request -> id) -> update($request->all());
   $pool->handleUpdate()
   return redirect("view");
}
```

And you should do Form Validation....and not save $request->all()